How to get top row of each unique value in particular column according to timestamp while combining 2 tables in SQL
Select top 1 dbo. Flow. id, dbo.Flow.code, dbo.Operation id, dbo.Operation. Flowid, dbo. Operation.Status, dbo. Operation.createdat, dbo. Operation.modifiedat, dbo. Operation.errormessage from dbo.Flow join dbo. Operation on dbo.Flow. Id dbo. Operation. FlowId
where dbo.Flow. Code in (BLV-PF-2,
CA-ARK-CH-PF,
CA COS-AU-EN-AU-PF) order by dbo.operation.ModifiedAt desc
It's not giving all the recent values for all the distinct codes.can anyone help me where the error in my code.
I tried the above code and was only getting one row that too for a single value . I need to top 1 rows for each distinct value I gave

You didn't have any operator on the JOIN condition - I just assume you most likely wanted a = (equality) - adapt if that's not the case. Also, the dbo.Flow.Code with the IN condition most likely should have the values in single quotes to signify string values

Which dbms are you using? TOP is a product specific construction.

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

You forgot to tell us which column you find particular.

I've given the keys in string format only it's not visible here. And I want to get the code column to produce all the codes that I given and I need only the latest ones . These codes will be running multiple times a day. So I can't be sure about what time this will run in the last. So I just sorted them in desc According to modified time and I want the top values of each code I gave.
